# Convert SUMPRODUCT Excel Formula to C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm beginner C# programmer and I find myself a problema in a Windows Form Application that I'm working on Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. I have a button that opens a file dialog to select a specific Excel workbook and then retrieve the values of the first column and the fith column of a specific Worksheet.

I have done this formula in Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Worksheet1'!$A$2:$A$700<=99999)*('Worksheet1'!$A$2:$A$700>=90000))
```

And I want to use this formula in C#. Anyone can help me with that?

Note that the name of the Worksheet is the same as the name of file so I can get the name of the Worksheet like this:

```
string name = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.Split(new Char[] { '.' })[0];
```

And then open it with:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

ExcelApp.Visible = true;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,) 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wbook.Sheets[name];
```

Can you guys help me with this? Hope you can.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean that you want to use the formula in C#? You want to insert it? You want to run it? ... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm for `SUMPRODUCT` having two same sized arrays would be easy... off my head:

```
float SumProduct(float[] arrayA, float[] arrayB)
{
   float result = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.Length; i++)
      result += arrayA[i] * arrayB[i];
   return result;
}
```

This could be easily expanded to use any number of arrays (or use any type different than `float`). You'd have to check that both arrays are the same size also.